# memset structure with std::string contained

Tags: c++

I have a massive structure where the entire contents is scalar variables, enumerations, and arrays of scalars (stack-based) with the exception of one std::string variable.

Now, here's my question...

Can I memset the structure to 0 for its whole size (like I would if it was simply all scalars), or is that not possible with the std::string being in there?  I'm not sure what memset would do to its internal representation.

And if you're going to say its good/bad please explain why - I'd like to know why it is the way it is :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, you cant, it would overwrite the internal state of the string and make bad things happen.  You could wrap all the POD stuff in a seperate struct and put that in your current one, that way you could memset that and let the string default construct.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, the string will almost certainly be storing a pointer to the memory its allocated for storage.  The string's constructor will always have run before you can memset it (even if you memset `this` in the constructor of your type, the string constructor would run first). So you would be overwriting this pointer value, and instead of pointing to its storage, it would a pointer to NULL, or some other almost definitely invalid value.

Comment: Not arguing `memset`ting an `std::string` to 0 is a bad idea, but it might actually work, assuming your `std:string` implementation does not allocate memory on construction. I'd imagine most `std::string`s have 3 pointers (begin, end, capacity) and a variable for size. If no allocation has been done it should be safe to set all of these to 0. Needless to say this would be non-portable.

Comment: Best case, by overwriting the pointers, you leak any memory allocated by the string.

Comment: @Praetorian - you're right, but its such a terrible idea i'd rather class it as something you can't do.

Comment: @Node I agree. Another thing I forgot when making my comment was if `std::string` derives from a base class with virtual functions then memsetting would overwrite the v-table and screw everything up. I'm not sure whether there's anything in the standard that prevents std::string` base classes from having virtual functions.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an exotic idea: Suppose your class `Foo` has lots of primitive members which remain uninitialized in `Foo`'s constructor, with the exception of one string:

```
class Foo
{
  int a;
  double b;
  std::string s;
};
```

The constructor `Foo::Foo()` will correctly initialize the string, but it won't care for anything else. So, let's zero out the memory *before* we construct!

```
void * addr = ::operator new(sizeof(Foo));
std::memset(addr, 0, sizeof(Foo));
Foo * p = new (addr) Foo;

// later

p->~Foo();
::operator delete(addr);
```

Of course it would be cleaner to just initialize all the members to zero in the constructor, but perhaps you have your own reasons that you don't want to create a custom constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Zeroing std::string member is very bad idea, it will cause memory leak! Never do this!

Comment: This question has been answered in far more details for years. This adds nothing to the discussion.

Comment: Yes, but I spent 2 hours figuring out where's leak. I think, it will be interesting for people to know that it can cause leak

Comment: The statement is incorrect. There is no requirement for a conforming implementation to cause a leak here. Indeed, the language specification makes **no promise at all** as to what the behavior should be. The behavior is thus undefined. Leaking memory is a valid form of undefined behavior, as much as *not* leaking memory is a valid form.