# C++ string assignment error. How to assign values to a string member of a struct pointer?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

Why the output of codes below is an invalid string? If lines #1 to #3 cannot be changed, how can I assign the value of `config.strConfig` to `data2->str`?

```cpp
// classA.h
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Config {
public:
    int a;
    std::string strConfig;
};

// structA.h
#pragma once

#include <string>

struct Data {
    char test[2];
    std::string str;
};

// main.cpp
#include "classA.h"
#include "structA.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Data data;  // #1
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));  // #2
    Data* data2 = &data;   // #3
    Config config;         
    config.strConfig = "aaaa";
    data2->str = config.strConfig;
    std::cout << (data2->str) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `memset` on a structure which is not POD.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877281/memset-structure-with-stdstring-contained

Comment: @Devolus thanks for commenting. However, lines #1 to #3 are codes written by other colleages, and I can only extend the program based on what they had given. I'm confused now how to achieve `data2->str = config.strConfig;` and get a valid result.

Comment: If your colleages gave you buggy code, then they should fix it.

Comment: You can not fix it, because if this is their implementation, and you can not change it, then there is nothing you can do about it until they fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need (and shouldn't use) memset (line // #2). This clears the memory bytes without taking into account the container type you are using. Better to write a constructor for Data which sets test[0] and test[1] to zero (if that's what you want) and (optionally) initialises str.